# OAuth lib that does not to authorization?

Tags: windows-phone-7, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to create a OAuth app for my application, and took a quick look on how Twitter does this. Works great, you enter username and passoword and it was game on.

But I tried ReactiveOAuth and it uses a webcontrol to show a authorize page and it feels a bit dated. not the way twitter does it.

Are there any other librarys for wp7 working with oauth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OAuth to be efficient and trusted, your user must sign in on the back-end platform via the website through HTTPS. Your application must never have the user's password in memory, all you got is an authorization token when the user has successfully authenticated itself.